# How to build instrumented APK with facebook BUCK

Tags: java, android, ant, emma, unit-testing

we use ant to build most of our android projects. now that facebook has come out its own build tool BUCK, we thought maybe it is a good time to give it a try. Building a debug/release apk with BUCK is really nice, I enjoyed using it so much. However, when we are trying to build instrumented APK for unit test on emulator, there seems to be no way. I know Android SDK include "instrument" target when running ant emma debug install test, I wonder is there a way to achieve same thing with BUCK? Many appreciations